# What is an efficient way to blind or hide parts of PDF file

Tags: pdf

For a blind study, I want to hide parts of scientific papers or to cut them out. Which free software can allow me to I hide parts of a PDF file? I am looking for the fastest method, because I have about 500 articles to manually process.

I have access to a windows 10 computer. So far my solution was to copy and paste the parts I want to keep in another file or to take screenshots and paint the parts I want to hide but this is taking too much time.

Comment: Simple, efficient and easy.... plus free https://www.pdfescape.com/open/—get to work on it since you are doing these articles manually though—to further automate such a task you'd like need adhered to standards.

Comment: Please give some more information – what have you already tried and why didn't that work for you, or what do you find inefficient about it? What operating system will you be using?